# Can't install Ball module

Tags: python

I am having a lot of trouble installing the Ball module, im running latest version of pip, python and im on windows 10. here is the error:

```
pip install ball
`Collecting ball
  Using cached Ball-0.2.9.tar.gz (348 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\davis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from ball) (1.19.5)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in c:\users\davis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from ball) (0.24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pygam in c:\users\davis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from ball) (0.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: progressbar2 in c:\users\davis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pygam->ball) (3.53.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\users\davis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pygam->ball) (1.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\users\davis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pygam->ball) (0.18.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\davis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from progressbar2->pygam->ball) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-utils>=2.3.0 in c:\users\davis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from progressbar2->pygam->ball) (2.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in c:\users\davis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn->ball) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in c:\users\davis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn->ball) (2.1.0)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for ball, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: ball
    Running setup.py install for ball ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\davis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Davis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0abie82x\\ball_2fc4c2cf6ca545768116429af36f95b5\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Davis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0abie82x\\ball_2fc4c2cf6ca545768116429af36f95b5\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Davis\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ly4riu7c\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\davis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\ball'
         cwd: C:\Users\Davis\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0abie82x\ball_2fc4c2cf6ca545768116429af36f95b5\
    Complete output (18 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Ball
    copying Ball\bcorsis.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Ball
    copying Ball\bcov.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Ball
    copying Ball\bd.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Ball
    copying Ball\cball.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Ball
    copying Ball\utilize.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Ball
    copying Ball\wrap_c.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Ball
    copying Ball\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Ball
    running build_ext
    building 'Ball._cball' extension
    swigging src/cball.i to src/cball_wrap.c
    swig.exe -python -o src/cball_wrap.c src/cball.i
    error: command 'swig.exe' failed: None
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\davis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Davis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0abie82x\\ball_2fc4c2cf6ca545768116429af36f95b5\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Davis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0abie82x\\ball_2fc4c2cf6ca545768116429af36f95b5\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Davis\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ly4riu7c\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\davis\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\ball' Check the logs for full command output.`
```

Comment: `pip` is trying to compile non-python code in ball, but you don't have some dependencies, like `swig.exe`. the [pypi page for ball](https://pypi.org/project/Ball/#files) has wheel files for python versions 3.5, 3.6, 3.7. If you downgrade to one of those versions, you will not need to compile ball.

Comment: @SiHa - ball does not have wheels for python 3.9, which OP seems to be using. see https://pypi.org/project/Ball/#files

Comment: @SiHa, I tried that, didn't work. RIP.

Comment: Fair enough - 'twas only a guess.